# Deezer OAuth API : You must specify a valid redirect_uri

Tags: react-native, expo, deezer

Expo SDK Version: 40.0.0

Platforms(Android/iOS/web/all): All

Hello everyone, I am actually trying to connect to the Deezer OAuth API. I follow the [AuthSession guide](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/auth-session/#useauthrequest) with the useAuthRequest hook.

Here is my code :

```js
import React, { useEffect, useCallback, useState } from "react";
import { makeRedirectUri, useAuthRequest } from "expo-auth-session";
import { Image, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from "react-native";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";

// Endpoint
const discovery = {
  authorizationEndpoint: "https://connect.deezer.com/oauth/auth.php?app_id=455342",
  tokenEndpoint: "https://connect.deezer.com/oauth/access_token.php",
};

const SignIn = () => {
  const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState();
  const [request, response, promptAsync] = useAuthRequest(
    {
      responseType: "token",
      usePKCE: false,
      // For usage in managed apps using the proxy
      redirectUri: makeRedirectUri({
        useProxy: true,
      }),
    },
    discovery
  );

  const storeToken = useCallback(
    async (token) => {
      try {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem("deezer_token", token);
        setAccessToken(token);
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
      }
    },
    [setAccessToken]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (response?.type === "success") {
      const { access_token } = response.params;
      storeToken(access_token);
    }
  }, [response, storeToken]);

  const handleDeezerConnect = () => {
    promptAsync({
      useProxy: true,
      redirectUri: makeRedirectUri({ useProxy: true }),
    });
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <TouchableOpacity style={{ backgroundColor: 'black', padding: 10 }} disabled={!request} onPress={handleDeezerConnect}>
        <Text style={{ color: 'white' }}>Connect with Deezer</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

export default SignIn;
```

The Deezer API docs say about the redirect_uri:
The URL the user will be redirected after authentication. redirect_uri must be in the same domain as the domain you defined when you created the application.

So I set the application domain to auth.expo.io

When I try to login to Deezer, my app open the Deezer web view to login but display the error message: You must specify a valid redirect_uri.

I display the Url and it seems to be good for me. (FYI, I already try the same code on another third party API and it works like a charm)

[image: Redirect URI]

[image: Deezer Error message]

Comment: the redirect uri that you set should be https://auth.expo.io/@yourusername/yourslug

Comment: Hello @brentvatne, Yes, it is actually

Comment: if you know 1) that the redirect uri specified in query params when going to "deezer" is correct and 2) that you have specified the correct allowed redirect uri on "deezer"s side, then either 1/2 are wrong or there is a bug with deezer's api